# keeping track of type with JSON.pm

Tags: json, perl

say i have the following inputted JSON object

```
{
   "field1": 21,
   "field2": "21",
   "field3": "hello"
}
```

is there any way with decode_json or from_json to know what the original type was (number verses string) of the values?  I know Perl generally doesnt care about type, but I have a need to know what the original type was.  I also know that perl does keep track of the type when creating a JSON object (so it does distinguish between "21" and 21 when creating a JSON object, so Im hoping there is a way to keep that information when decoding/'from'ming it.

I don't want to base it on the field name, because im trying to write something that will be used somewhat generically, and fieldnames could change.

Comment: That isn't JSON. http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Just out of morbid curiosity...why do you need to treat `21` and `"21"` differently?

Comment: ive been offline for a while..  has to do with mongo and mongoose.  converting perl objects to proper mongo fields before sending them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using JSON::XS, the type of the value in the scalar matches the type of the value in the document.

```
$ perl -e'
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use B        qw( svref_2object SVf_IOK SVf_NOK SVf_POK );
   use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

   my $data = decode_json(q{[ "4", 4, 4.0, 20000000000000000000 ]});

   for my $i (0..$#$data) {
      my $sv = svref_2object(\( $data->[$i] ));
      my $flags = $sv->FLAGS;
      printf("Scalar %s has %s\n",
         $i,
         join(",",
            $flags & SVf_POK ? "PV" : (),
            $flags & SVf_IOK ? "IV" : (),
            $flags & SVf_NOK ? "NV" : (),
         ),
      );
   }
'
Scalar 0 has PV
Scalar 1 has IV
Scalar 2 has NV
Scalar 3 has PV
```

As you can see, the fourth scalar is an exception when using JSON::XS. JSON::XS stores very large numbers as strings to avoid loosing precision.

You get similar results with JSON::PP:

```
Scalar 0 has PV
Scalar 1 has IV
Scalar 2 has NV
Scalar 3 has NV
```

Comment: This is obviously an edge case, but JSON numbers that consist of only digits and cannot be represented as numeric in Perl without loss of precision are represented as strings.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I incorporated your comment into my answer. Note that JSON::PP stored the large number as an NV.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think to test with `JSON::PP`. Looks like the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP#number) needs to be updated since there's no mention of that particular difference.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Actually, 20000000000000000000 can be stored in an NV without loss. But JSON::PP also stores 20000000000000000001 as an NV.

Comment: we ended doing something different, but i accepted your answer.  sorry for the long delay, never got back to this question.